# Docker - invalid sharing of index.html Nginx file

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I have my docker-compose.yml file like so:

```
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  volumes:
    - /c/Users/marcin/docker/nginx-www/nginx/html/:/usr/share/nginx/html/ 
  ports:
    - "80:80"
```

In `/c/Users/marcin/docker/nginx-www/nginx/html/` I've created `index.html` file with the following content:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
hello index
</body>
</html>
```

but when I look at my domain I see empty page, but looking in page source I see something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
```

It seems Docker is using default Nginx file and takes only part of it (probably the exact length of it as it is in my `index.html` file. With other files for example `abc.html` there's no such issue (probably because it does not exist by default in Nginx image). How can I solve this issue to display correct content of `index.html` file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your volume starts with `/c/...`, I'm assuming that you're using the Docker Toolbox on Windows and the `docker-machine` tool shipped with it. What you're experiencing is a [known issue](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9069) of Nginx (or rather the `sendfile` Linux system call that Nginx uses) in conjunction with Virtualbox shared folders.

This issue is also mentioned in the [Vagrant documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/virtualbox.html) (which also uses VirtualBox), which also comes with a suggested solution that might work for you:

> There is a VirtualBox bug related to sendfile which can result in corrupted or non-updating files. You should deactivate sendfile in any web servers you may be running.
>
> In Nginx:
>
> ```
> sendfile off;
> ```
>
> In Apache:
>
> ```
> EnableSendfile Off
> ```

According to the latest comments in the [bug report in the vendor bug tracker](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9069), if you're using the `open_file_cache` directive (disabled by default), you'll need to turn that off, too:

```
open_file_cache off;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I've added it to nginx conf it's not working without a problem. All changes of files are now reflected on webserver